# How to upload file to server when creating downloadable product

Tags: magento-1, product

I am creating downloadable product type in `magento 1.7`, product is created successfully but files are not uploaded to server check the below images where sample > file and file > file showing nothing.

[image: Downloadable product > Downloadable inforamation Tab]

I have try below code

```
try {
        $api = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api();

        $attribute_api = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Set_Api();
        $attribute_sets = $attribute_api->items();

        $sku = date('YmdHis');

        $productData = array();
        $productData['website_ids'] = array(1);
        $productData['categories'] = array(23);

        $productData['status'] = 1;

        $productData['name'] = utf8_encode('product'.date('ymdis'));
        $productData['description'] = utf8_encode('limit desc');
        $productData['short_description'] = utf8_encode('limit short');
        $productData['price'] = 12.34;
        $productData['weight'] = 0;
        $productData['tax_class_id'] = 0;
        $productData['page_layout'] ='two_columns_left';

        $new_product_id = $api->create('downloadable',$attribute_sets[0]['set_id'],$sku,$productData);

        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
        $stockItem->loadByProduct( $new_product_id );

        $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('qty', 100);
        $stockItem->setData('min_qty', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_qty', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 0);
        $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('max_sale_qty', 0);
        $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('is_qty_decimal', 0);
        $stockItem->setData('backorders', 0);
        $stockItem->setData('notify_stock_qty', 0);
        $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
        $stockItem->setData('tax_class_id', 0);

        $stockItem->save();

        foreach($links as $key => $link) {

            Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')->setData(array(
                    'product_id' => $new_product_id,
                    'sort_order' => 0,
                    'number_of_downloads' => 0, // Unlimited downloads
                    'is_shareable' => 0, // Not shareable
                    'link_url' => '',
                    'link_type' => 'file',
                    'link_file' => array('file' => array('http://localhost/magento/media/highres/Hydrangeas.jpg')),
                    'sample_url' => '',
                    'sample_file' => array( 'file' => array('http://localhost/magento/media/highres/Tulips.jpg')),
                    'sample_type' => 'file',
                    'use_default_title' => false,
                    'title' => $link['title'],
                    'store_id' => $key,
                    'website_id' => $productData['website_ids'],
            ))->save();
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($new_product_id);

        $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery ('C://xampp/htdocs/magento/media/highres/Hydrangeas.jpg', array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        $product->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception : ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You should upload the files first and set the relative path then.
You can use the `Varien_File_Uploader` for the upload.
Furthermore, the downloadable files are usually stored in

```
/media/downloadable/files/link_samples/[first_letter_of_filename]/[2nd_letter_of_filename]/filename.jpg
/media/downloadable/files/links/[first_letter_of_filename]/[2nd_letter_of_filename]/filename.jpg
/media/downloadable/files/samples/[first_letter_of_filename]/[2nd_letter_of_filename]/filename.jpg
```

Example: `/media/downloadable/files/links/f/i/filename.jpg`

`http://localhost/magento/media/highres/Hydrangeas.jpg` is a full URL.

So, if I have a look in my downloadable_link database table, the path in link_file is:

```
/f/i/filename.jpg
```

Depending on the type (link_sample, link, sample) the path is relative to the upper directory (/link_samples/, /links/, /samples/).

Answer (score 0):

If the upload in the product configuration does not work, upload the files via FTP and set the URL in the respective product configuration.
The file upload only works when the directory is writable.

Comment: I have tried same but still doesn't work also checked that directory is writable.

Comment: Have you checked the server configuration? Is there anywhere a restriction to upload files?

Have you checked if your server is completely compatible? [http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento)