# How to save samples in downloadable product programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, downloadable

I want to add samples in downloadable product programmatically.

I am trying this

```
 $samplefiles[] = array(
                    'file' => '/u/n/untitled_1.png',
                    'name' => 'Untitled.png',
                    'size' => 4672,
                    'status' => 'new'
            );
 $sampleModel = Mage::getModel('downloadable/sample')->setData(array(
                    'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                    'sort_order' => 0,
                    'sample_url' => '',
                    'sample_file' => json_encode($samplefiles),
                    'sample_type' => 'url',
            ));
            $sampleModel->save();
```

But its not working..And how to save sample title

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/490/how-to-upload-file-to-server-when-creating-downloadable-product

Comment: This thread will help you with your requirements.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45576/magento-add-downloadable-product-programmatically-downloadable-information-ti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not save file at system.

As you have **using url as sample type(`sample_type`) ('sample_type' => 'url')`** that magento **does not save file in system  and it just save a link**.

If you want to `upload image to magento  and want to set  file` as sample type ,then you need to  follow below steps:

1. Upload image using `Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader` at
   `media/downloadable/files/samples` or move  file at that location
2. and set sample type and file location at sample_file

**Code:**

```
 $sampleModel = Mage::getModel('downloadable/sample')->setData(array(
                    'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                    'sort_order' => 0,
                    'sample_url' => '/u/n/untitled_1.png',
                    'sample_file' => '',
                    'sample_type' => 'file',
                     'title' =>'mYtitle'
    ));
    $sampleModel->save();
```

[image]

**And  database:**

[image]